# How to tell .find() to find correct id if name values are duplicated?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

In my app, I have a input with typeahead (autocomplete). So far, it's been working great, but I found some problem with duplicated `name` values. I have to send `id` of `name` and my typeahead suggests `name` values. If I type a `name` that is duplicated, no matter which one duplicated value from typeahead I choose, it's always sending `id` of first object on the list.

How can I tell `.find()` to search for choosen value, not the first one the list? Right now, if I input 'wolny' into input field and press enter, it will pass the `464` value of `WOLNY`. Even if I click on, for example, 'WOLNY' with `619` value, it's still pass `464`.

I cannot suggest `id`'s in typeahead becasue:

- Project require to input names, not ids
- API given to me doesn't accept names

I use typeahead for ngx-bootstrap library.
This is how the typeahead looks like (grey numbers are `id`'s of specific `name`s):

[image]

**Service - Typeahead**

```
    searchVehicleId(description?: string) {
    const url = (!description) ? this.defUrl : 'API=' + description;
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map(res => res.json().vehicles);
  }
```

**Component**

```
export class VehicleComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {

this.vehicleIdDataSource = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
  this.vehicleService.searchVehicleId(this.vehicleIdAsyncSelected)
    .subscribe((result: any) => {
      observer.next(result);
    })
});
    this.searchQuery = new FormGroup({
      vehiclename: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
  }
  public vehicle: Vehicle[];
  public description: Description[];
  public searchVehicleId: any;

  public vehicleIdDataSource: Observable<any>;
  public vehicleIdAsyncSelected: string = "";

    public searchByVehicleId(searchQuery) {
    this.vehicleService
      .searchVehicleId(searchQuery.value.vehiclename)
      .subscribe(searchQuery => {
        this.description = searchQuery;
        this.searchVehicleId = this.description.find(x => x.id === x.id).id;
        let qwe = this.description.filter(x => x.id === x.id).map(x => x.id);

        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.description));
        console.log("filter(): " + qwe);
        console.log("find(): " + this.searchVehicleId);

        this.vehicleService
          .getVehicleByVehicleId(this.searchVehicleId)
          .subscribe(searchQuery => {
            this.vehicle = searchQuery;
          })
      });

    interface Description {
      vehicle_id: number;
      custom_description: string;
      description: string;
    }

interface Vehicle {
  status: number;
  dallases: Vehicle[];
}

interface VehicleDetails {
  vehicle_id: number;
  dallassettings: string;
  dallasupdated: string;
  dallas_list: DallasList[];
}

interface DallasList {
  number: number;
  auth: number;
}
```

**Template**

```
<input class="form-control" formControlName="vehiclename" [(ngModel)]="vehicleIdAsyncSelected" [typeahead]="vehicleIdDataSource"
  typeaheadMinLenght="2" typeaheadOptionsLimit="10" typeaheadGroupField="id" typeaheadOptionField="description" typeaheadWaitMs="100"
  placeholder="Search">
```

Thanks

Comment: You send `vehicleid` to `vehicleService.searchVehicleId`. What do you expect back? It should probably return instance of `Vehicle`. Then you will have `subscribe(vehicle)`.

Comment: I named this wrong, it should be `vehiclename`. I send it to API and get back list of vehicles that contains id and description of vehicle.

Comment: What does `description` contain... is that what you refer to as *list of vehicles that contains id and description of vehicle* (s)?

Comment: There is still info missing though... what does `searchQuery.value` contain (other than `vehiclename`)? Does it contain id? Your problem is though with your `find()`. Take a close look at: `this.description.find(x => x.id === x.id)` You are comparing `x.id` with `x.id`, which means that it will return the first item from your `description`, since of course `x.id` will be the same as `x.id`. You should compare it with the actual id you want to compare to... so something like: `this.description.find(x => x.id === the Id here you want found)`

Comment: `searchQuery` is a form group with field `vehiclename` where you input vehicle name. I understand a bit better why `.find()` works like that, thanks to you. I'm afraid, I have nothing that could help us identify which one duplicated value from typeahead has been choosen.

Comment: Since you are able to display the id in your typeahead, is there no way to extract the id from it... then the find could be something like.. : `this.description.find(x => x.id === searchQuery.value.id)`?

Comment: That would work if I could actually type the id in input, too bad the requirement is to type vehicle names, not id's. I guess, there's no possible solution to this.

Comment: Yes I understand you are typing names. But I see that the id is present in your type ahead. So I assume that what you are feeding the typeahead is an array of objects... something like: `[{id:1,name:'name'}....]` so when you choose an object from the typeahead, it would contain id and name, which you can compare the id with the list of vehicles you are receiving.

Comment: I've done another edit, added typeahead service, template and how I search for values in component - observer in `onInit`. The `id` above values in typeahead are made by `typeaheadGroupField="id"`

Comment: I'm not familiar with this typeahead. But can't you bind the whole object using `[ngValue]`, so that you could catch the name and id, or does it only support primitive types? If so, maybe you should consider using another typeahead that supports binding objects. You need to get a hold of the complete object when choosing one, so that you can compare the id. So when you choose e.g wolny with id 862 you would end up with the complete object from which you can then compare the id, when receiving the list of vehicles with the name wolny.